# Accessing internal function of a class in C#

Tags: c#, dll

I am trying to build a console app, where I need to use the given dll and use the classes in them. I am trying to access a class which is public but has internal constructor. I am not sure how to access it and use it's functionality. I am new to C#. Maybe I am missing some concept.

Given is the class:

```cs
namespace tt_net_sdk
{
    public class PositionStatistics
    {
        private decimal totalBuyPrice_;

        private decimal buyPosition_;

        private int fillCount_;

        private decimal totalSellPrice_;

        private decimal sellPosition_;

        public decimal BuyAveragePrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (!(buyPosition_ > 0m))
                {
                    return 0m;
                }

                return totalBuyPrice_ / buyPosition_;
            }
        }

        public decimal BuyPosition => buyPosition_;

        public int FillCount => fillCount_;

        public decimal NetPosition => buyPosition_ - sellPosition_;

        public decimal SellAveragePrice
        {
            get
            {
                if (!(sellPosition_ > 0m))
                {
                    return 0m;
                }

                return totalSellPrice_ / sellPosition_;
            }
        }

        public decimal SellPosition => sellPosition_;

        internal PositionStatistics()
        {
            totalBuyPrice_ = default(decimal);
            buyPosition_ = default(decimal);
            fillCount_ = 0;
            totalSellPrice_ = default(decimal);
            sellPosition_ = default(decimal);
        }

        internal PositionStatistics(decimal buyAveragePrice, decimal buyPosition, int fillCount, decimal sellAveragePrice, decimal sellPosition)
        {
            totalBuyPrice_ = buyAveragePrice;
            buyPosition_ = buyPosition;
            fillCount_ = fillCount;
            totalSellPrice_ = sellAveragePrice;
            sellPosition_ = sellPosition;
        }

        internal PositionStatistics(PositionStatistics other)
        {
            totalBuyPrice_ = other.totalBuyPrice_;
            buyPosition_ = other.buyPosition_;
            fillCount_ = other.fillCount_;
            totalSellPrice_ = other.totalSellPrice_;
            sellPosition_ = other.sellPosition_;
        }

        internal void Clear()
        {
            totalBuyPrice_ = default(decimal);
            buyPosition_ = default(decimal);
            fillCount_ = 0;
            totalSellPrice_ = default(decimal);
            sellPosition_ = default(decimal);
        }

        internal void AddFill(BuySell side, decimal quantity, decimal totalFillPrice)
        {
            if (side == BuySell.Buy)
            {
                buyPosition_ += quantity;
                totalBuyPrice_ += totalFillPrice;
            }
            else
            {
                sellPosition_ += quantity;
                totalSellPrice_ += totalFillPrice;
            }

            fillCount_++;
        }

        internal void AdjustFill(BuySell side, decimal oldQuantity, decimal oldTotalFillPrice, decimal newQuantity, decimal newTotalFillPrice)
        {
            if (side == BuySell.Buy)
            {
                buyPosition_ -= oldQuantity;
                totalBuyPrice_ -= oldTotalFillPrice;
                buyPosition_ += newQuantity;
                totalBuyPrice_ += newTotalFillPrice;
            }
            else
            {
                sellPosition_ -= oldQuantity;
                totalSellPrice_ -= oldTotalFillPrice;
                sellPosition_ += newQuantity;
                totalSellPrice_ += newTotalFillPrice;
            }

            fillCount_++;
        }

        internal void RemoveFill(BuySell side, decimal quantity, decimal totalFillPrice)
        {
            if (side == BuySell.Buy)
            {
                buyPosition_ -= quantity;
                totalBuyPrice_ -= totalFillPrice;
            }
            else
            {
                sellPosition_ -= quantity;
                totalSellPrice_ -= totalFillPrice;
            }

            fillCount_--;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"b:{BuyPosition}@{BuyAveragePrice} S:{SellPosition}@{SellAveragePrice} F:{FillCount} NetPos:{NetPosition}";
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying:

```cs
tt_net_sdk.PositionStatistics ps = new tt_net_sdk.PositionStatistics(); // gives error
```

I have also tried:

```cs
tt_net_sdk.PositionStatistics ps = (tt_net_sdk.PositionStatistics)typeof(tt_net_sdk.PositionStatistics).GetConstructor(
                  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                  null, Type.EmptyTypes, null).Invoke(null); // gives wrong result
```

But it's not giving me the current result. Maybe the class is used in some other class in the assembly.

I am also attaching the docs for the api.

https://library.tradingtechnologies.com/tt-net-sdk/api/tt_net_sdk.PositionStatistics.html

Comment: Perhaps that class is only intended to be created by methods within the library? For example, via [`TradeSubscription.PositionStatistics`](https://library.tradingtechnologies.com/tt-net-sdk/api/tt_net_sdk.TradeSubscription.html#tt_net_sdk_TradeSubscription_PositionStatistics)

Comment: An internal constructor is only called from inside the class and not externally.  You are calling the constructor with no parameters.  The solution is to add to the class another constructor with zero parameters : public PositionStatistics() { }

Comment: Note that the docs you reference don't mention any constructors.  It sounds like the library doesn't *intend* for instances to be created directly from consuming code.

Comment: It's not clear if you use a 3rd party library or if you have the control of the code. If 1. reflection is a way to hijack the safeguards created by the author of the lib. Most of time it's a bad idea (but if the library is not a good one, there are some case where it can save a life); If it's 2nd, go to suggestion of other to create proper contructor

Comment: @jdweng: The class already has an internal constructor with no parameters - you can't add a public one as well. (And I assume that the OP isn't actually able to modify the code.)

Comment: @JonSkeet : The OP need to then change the no parameter constructor to public.

Comment: As @MatthewWatson indicated the `TradeSubscription` class has a `PositionStatistics` property that returns a `PositionStatistics` object. The properties of `PositionStatistics` are read-only. The client of the API is not intended to create or modify a `PositionStatistics` object. Why is there a need to subvert the library's intentions?

Comment: @jdweng `PositionStatistics` is an immutable object and represents information returned by an API call. The library was designed to prohibit the API client from constructing a `PositionStatistics` object. I suspect this is an XY problem and/or an issue of creating unit tests.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have modified my code and had very little idea about reflection. I was trying to find more about internal constructor and learn about it. As @MatthewWatson pointed out we can use the Tradesubscription.PositionStatistics to create it.

I was bit confused since I am new to C#. After reading the comment a lot of things are clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `internal` access modifier is placed on things such that only classes within their same assembly (often project) can access them. `internal` is equivalent to "public, but only for this project/assembly/library/.dll/."

The constructor for `PositionStatistics` can only be called within the assembly. To obtain instances of `PositionStatistics` outside of the assembly, there would have to be methods within the assembly returning `PositionStatistics` to you. For you to directly call the constructor from outside of the  .dll containing the namespace`tt_net_sdk`, there would need to be a `PositionStatistics` constructor marked as public.